# How to get current Subclipse commit author name in Eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, version-control, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I am creating a plug-in for Eclipse that interacts with the Subclipse plug-in. One thing I would like to do is access the username (commit author name) that the person uses for accessing their Subversion repository(ies). For a simple case, I am assuming the person only has 1 repository checked out into their workspace and that I am only interested in the username that they use for that workspace, how can I access it?

Note: The simple case illustrates the problem I am trying to address, but I still need it to generalize to a scenario where there are potentially multiple repositories open.

I know that this information is stored somewhere because when I try to make a commit and Subclipse asks me to confirm my credentials, it has the username pre-filled out and I just have to enter my password.

How can I go about doing this?

Here is something I have tried, but doesn't work:

```
String uname = "";
try {
    uname = SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getRepository("https://<path-to-my-repository>").getUsername();
} catch (SVNException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Username: " + uname);
```

However, this outputs: `Username:` which tells me that the string uname is getting `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclipse does not know what the user's username is so there is no way to get this from Subclipse.  About the only way you could do it would be to try to read Subversion's cache files, but even that will not work if they are using SVNKit as it has its own cache.

Comment: When I attempt to commit through Subclipse, a dialog box appears in order to get my credentials for accessing the repo. The dialog box already has my username entered (it remembers this from my original access of the repo). Where is this being stored? Is this Subclipse or Subversion storing this? Can I access this?

Comment: Subclipse registers some callback functions with the SVN API before calling it.  SVN uses these callbacks to ask for information such as credentials.  SVN passes the username into the callback.  You can set a default username in your ~/.subversion/servers file, but otherwise I believe it uses your current login.  Of course once a value a value is cached that is what it uses.  Subclipse never knows the values, we are just providing a dialog that the API can use to ask for information.

Comment: Would it be possible for my plug-in to use those callback functions in a similar way to access the current login information? Which class(es) in Subclipse could I look at to see how these callback functions are implemented?

Comment: No, you could not replace the callback functions and they still do not give you access to the usernames since they are only called when SVN does not already know it.  You really would need to learn how to read the SVN cache and configuration to have any chance to do this.